# Amazon SP API ISO Date with Postman

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Amazon says:
A time interval used for selecting order metrics. This takes the form of two dates separated by two hyphens (first date is inclusive; second date is exclusive). Dates are in ISO8601 format and must represent absolute time (either Z notation or offset notation). Example: 2018-09-01T00:00:00-07:00--2018-09-04T00:00:00-07:00 requests order metrics for Sept 1st, 2nd and 3rd in the -07:00 zone.

2018-09-01T00:00:00+01:00--2018-09-04T00:00:00+01:00 but getting error.
If i replace + with - it works however this will not be the GMT +1 Timezone?

url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/sales/v1/xxxxxxxxx&interval=2018-09-01T00:00:00+01:00--2018-09-04T00:00:00+01:00&granularity=Day"

Was expecting this to work but it doesn't?

Comment: I've got the same issue except with +10:00.

"message": "{getOrderMetrics.arg1=must match \"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\\.[0-9]{3})?(([+-]\\d\\d:\\d\\d)|Z)(\\[[a-zA-Z/_]+\\])?--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\\.[0-9]{3})?(([+-]\\d\\d:\\d\\d)|Z)(\\[[a-zA-Z/_]+\\])?\"}"

The error seems to indicate that + is accepted...